# What’s the explicit description of the perverse cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is the explicit description/construction of the $l$-adic étale perverse sheaf cohomology $\phantom{}^pH^0=\phantom{}^p\tau_{\geq0} \phantom{}^p\tau_{\leq0}$? Specifically, I want a description more explicit than the “it’s an adjoint functor” given in Kiehl-Weissauer III.1.